# AndroidX Kotlin, binding adapter Cannot find the setter for attribute with parameter type

Tags: android, kotlin

So, learning android new architechture compoment with androidx and can't get a simple binding adapter to work

so, here is a is a simple text view

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
                name="viewmodel"
            type="com.cleanandroidlearning.ui.livedatafunfragment.LiveDataFunViewModel" />
</data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.widget.TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="test"
                app:testBindingAdapter="@{viewmodel.test}"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

and the binding adapter

```
@BindingAdapter("app:testBindingAdapter")
fun testBindingColisse(view: View, value: Int) {

}
```

and the view model is quite simple

```
class LiveDataFunViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    var test: Int = 0
}
```

but I always get this error

```
android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
  ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:testBindingAdapter' with parameter type int on android.widget.TextView. file:/Users/kenny/working/cleanandroidlearning/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_live_data_fun.xml loc:18:42 - 18:55 ****\ data binding error ****
```

any of you can see what I can't see or have an example done with the same architecture?

EDIT: find the problem

Was missing

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

in the module graddle file

Comment: I couldn't see any issue with the code. Have you tried Clean and Rebuild project.